# Warp markers in Ableton not correct anymore when replacing with higher quality song

Tags: ableton-live

I've added warp markers throughout the track Kool & The Gang - Celebration. Everything sounds good now but I found a high quality FLAC version. So I replaced the song with it. And now my warp markers are all offset.

after analyzing I found that the same tracks are the same length (3:41) but the lower quality starts earlier and has a little sound artefact (less than a second). I've added the same amount of time before the FLAC version and the warp markers are still not correct.

Should I redo all the markers or is there a faster way? It took me about 4 hours.

[image]

Comment: Are they all off by the same amount? Could you just slide the track so they line up?

Comment: that's what I tried, but it didn't work. They are all offset.

Comment: You should have at least tried to slide the new track into sync with the old one before trashing it. You now don't even have a proper sample-accurate visual guide, just some hand-made markers.

Comment: the top track is the one with the markers I can just replace it with any track.

Comment: Is there some particular reason why you haven't lined up the audio clip's beat grid with the audio? It looks like bar/beat 1 of the audio clip is not lined up with the actual first beat. Wouldn't it be easier to handle if you lined it up?